# What does "言葉の裏の想いが 心の首筋舐めた" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

I was listening to the song Ain't Nobody Know by Gen Hoshino and looking up the translation, which said for this sentence "the feelings behind our words licked the back of our hearts' neck". Since English isn't my first language I looked up what "licking the back of heart's neck" meant, thinking it was an English expression but I didn't find anything so I think it was a literal translation of the Japanese expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is a personal interpretation, but the expression that the thought behind the words was a shock is a zodiacal analogy.
Actually licking my neck muscles = tingling = piercing my heart.

首筋を舐められる＝ゾクゾクする＝心に突き刺さった。